# td within a tr in Chrome is off by 4 pixels in width

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

If you use this code in Chrome, you get a td with the number 4 in it, indicating the width of the td is 4 pixels smaller than the tr.  If you do it in Firefox, you get 0.  If you add "display:block" to both of the css definition, it changes to 0.  My question is, where in the world is Chrome getting the 4 extra pixels from?

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/te4L9/8/)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Hey</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS (with jQuery):

```
jQuery(document).ready(
function () {
    var td = $("td");
    var tr = $("tr");
    td.text(tr.width() - td.width());
});
```

CSS:

```
tr{
  background-color:red;
}
td {
  padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Did you use Chromes inspector to see if you could determine any CSS rules Chrome might be applying?

Comment: Chrome is showing the `tr` at 31px, while Firefox shows it at `27px`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Chrome's inspector, you will find this style being applied:

```
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Border-spacing of 2 (times 2 sides) = the mysterious 4 pixels.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jphS/)

So, to overcome this, add this to your stylesheet:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

And now Firefox and Chrome both provide the same response to the `tr.width()`.

Comment: Thank you!  Now if the border-spacing is the reason it's off by 4, why would I change the border-collapse and not the border-spacing itself? Is there a benefit to border-collapse:collapse as opposed to border-spacing:0px?

Comment: `border-collapse` is the root cause.  Changing it eliminates `border-spacing`.  Changing `border-spacing` simply changes the spacing, but leaves the `border-collapse` at whichever value it was previously.  Better to take care if the issue at the root for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS rule to your CSS and you will always get it to `0`

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Here `border-collapse` CSS rule is part of CSS reset.

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/te4L9/10/)

Why??

Some -webkit browser are having default user agent properties since tables have `border-collapse:separate` rule, so always try to use [Css Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) before you start to design any website, it's a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, a table has a default border spacing off 2 pixels. If you set border-spacing to 0 on the table selector, you will get 0 printed out.
Your css will look something like this:

```
table{
     border-spacing: 0;
}
tr{
     background-color: red;
}
td{
     padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont get what you mean... It does work like this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9LJA/)

Comment: The defined border-spacing is 2px, not 4px.  That statement is incorrect in your answer.

Comment: Oh right, I guess I said it like that because it has spacing on both sides, which totals to 4